# I recovered a deleted .class file, however when i am trying to run it using java it gives classFormatException?

Tags: java, swing, class, recover

I had deleted a complete folder by mistake and had to use a data recovery software. However I could find only the .class files of my java program. The DE-compilers on net are giving error.
Even when I am trying to run the class file from command line using java..it gives incompatible magic value: 4292411361

1)How can I correct this error and run my program from the class file i just recovered?
2)How can I DE-compile this class file?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it is a matter if decomiling the .class file, I would reccomend you user [JD GUI](http://jd-gui.softpedia.com/)

It is free and quite good in .class decompiling.
Then you can rebuild the Class file.

Answer (score 0):

1)may be Your class file not  recovered properly.if recovered properly try the below solution

2)we can use jad compiler to get the source file from .classfile.Download the jad compiler.we get a zip file,unzip it.you will find a .exe file in the folder.

place the .class file in the same folder.

use the command 
     jad -sjava Filename.class in cmd.